# Keep getting error "Call to undefined function curl_init()"

Tags: 14.04, server, apache2, php, curl

I'm using PHP 5.6. I've already installed curl using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install php-curl
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

But even still, I keep getting the error:

> Call to undefined function curl_init()

However, when I `locate curl.ini`, it shows this:

```
/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-curl.ini
/etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/20-curl.ini
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
/etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-curl.ini
/etc/php5/mods-available/curl.ini
/usr/share/php5/curl/curl.ini
/var/lib/ucf/cache/:etc:php5:mods-available:curl.ini
```

And when I `locate curl.so`, it shows this:

```
/usr/lib/php5/20131226/curl.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.3.0
```

So I changed the line in `/etc/php5/mods-available/curl.ini` from:

extension=curl.so

To:

extension=/usr/lib/php5/20131226/curl.so

But I'm **still** getting the error.

What's wrong?

Comment: Try `php5enmod curl` followed by a restart of your webserver

Answer (score 0):

Try these two things:

`sudo apt-get install php5.6-curl`

create a page to show you `<?php phpinfo();` and make sure that you're using php 5.6. Do you have multiple php's installed? Once you figure out which exact version you are using, install curl for it: `apt-get install php<VERSION>-curl -y`